# How to reuse result of calculated field in a view

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, view

I have a view contstructed like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myview] AS
SELECT   
       dbo.table1.field1
      ,dbo.table2.field2  
      ,dbo.HeavyStoredProcedure(dbo.table1.field1) AS calculated_value 
      ...
FROM
      table1
      INNER JOIN table2 ON (...)
WHERE  
      ...
      AND NOT( EXISTS (SELECT * from table3 
               WHERE (table3.somefield = dbo.HeavyStoredProcedure(dbo.table1.field1)))
               OR
               EXISTS (SELECT * from table4
               WHERE (table4.anotherfield = dbo.HeavyStoredProcedure(dbo.table1.field1)))
             )
```

The problem here is that the **"HeavyStoredProcedure"** gets called numerous times with the *exact same argument*, thus slowing down the whole thing to a crawl.

How can I make my view just call **"HeavyStoredProcedure"** once per row in table1 and then reuse the calculated result twice in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server try this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myview] AS
SELECT   
       dbo.table1.field1
      ,dbo.table2.field2  
      ,
      ...
FROM
      table1
      INNER JOIN table2 ON (...)
      outer apply (
          select dbo.HeavyStoredProcedure(dbo.table1.field1) AS calculated_value 
      ) as CALC
WHERE  
      ...
      AND NOT( EXISTS (SELECT * from table3 
               WHERE (table3.somefield = CALC.calculated_value))
               OR
               EXISTS (SELECT * from table4
               WHERE (table4.anotherfield = CALC.calculated_value))
             )
```